# Function is not found in Knitr

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr

I had an odd question when compiling the following document. `se.ranef(model)` and `se.fixef(model)` worked fine in `R`. However, as the following picture shows, suddenly, they could not be found. What went wrong, please? Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{exam}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\printanswers
\unframedsolutions

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question 

\begin{solution}

<<>>=
library(lme4)
X <- 1:24
coag <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 
          71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
diet <- c("A", "A", "A",  "A",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B", "C", 
          "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D",  "D", "D", "D", "D")
#coag <- data.frame(cbind(X, coag, diet))
#coag <- read.table("coag.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
model <- lmer(coag~(1|diet))
@

<<>>=
se.ranef(model)
@

<<>>=
se.fixef(model)
@

\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`se.fixef` and `se.ranef` are functions not from base, or `nlme`. `knitr` starts a new environment when you run it, so any other packages are not loaded.

Try loading the library you got them from first, add this to where you load `nlme`:

```
library(arm)
```

Comment: Maybe there is also an error in the LaTeX code because your solution does not work for me. Could you please be more precise?

Comment: the error still exists. as I said it is not a R problem but a LaTeX one. I'll try to investigate the log file.

Comment: it works fine for me - pasting above into RStudio as a .rnw and hitting compile .pdf. R version 3.2.1, knitr_1.10.5, RStudio Version 0.99.441